# Connecting to SQL Server database via Web service

Tags: web-services, delphi, dbexpress

1.) I can create a simple application which has one routine called

```
function ConnectToDB: Boolean
```

and run it from my virtual directory (wwwroot/cgi-bin) and it connects and reports back connected .

2.) I can create a simple web service helloWorld

```
function helloWorld: String;stdcall;
```

I can create a client and call my web service call "helloWorld "and get my "HELLO WORLD" string reported back to me - everything works great.

3.) NOW, if i take my connection code from step one (1) and put it into a web service, i can not connect to the DB. It always reports back false.

Note: I am Using Delphi 7 to create my web service. I am using DBXpress as the conduit to the MS SQL Server DB, and the two INI files (dbxconnections.ini, dbxdrivers.ini) and two DLL's required for the connection reside in the same folder as the executables (wwwroot/cgi-bin).

Any help would ge greatly appreciated!  Again, please be aware of steps 1 & 2, before responding.

Thanx!

Comment: 'i can not connect to the DB' is not really something we can help you with. If you debug the appliation do you het an error message?

Comment: If you post code samples, even just a function declaration, *please* use the "code" button (101 010) from the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax-highlight those lines - makes a world of a difference!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How does the connection connect - does it use integrated windows authentication, or do use sql authentication - could it be that integrated auth doesn't work because iis is running as another user.

Also, when you connect, are you ensuring you disable the username/password prompt?